# How can I prevent the white background coming up by default with the soft keyboard on a Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a samsung galaxy phone where if I run my android application in landscape, and go to edit an EditText, the soft keyboard pops up, but a white background pops up where you type the text into.  I believe this is default behavior for the samsung galaxy s3 because it happens in many apps, but the browser just has the soft keyboard pop up lik normal.  Does anyone know how I can turn this behavior off so a white background doesn't pop up?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following options to the imeOptions of the text field:  flagNoFullscreen, flagNoExtractUi.

Most keyboards will respect these flags.